# Python Pandas calculate standard deviation excluding current group, with vectorization solution

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, standard-deviation

So i want to calculate standard deviation excluding current group using groupby. Here an example of the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({
                      'group' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                      'team'  : ['1','1','2','2','3','3','1','1','2','2','3','3',]
                      'value' : [1,2,5,7,2,3,7,8,8,9,6,4]
                  })
```

For example, for group A team 1, i want to calculate the std dev of team 2 and 3, for group A team 2, i want to calculate the std dev of group 1 and 3, and so on.

I managed to do it using groupby and apply but when using it on real data with literally milion of rows, it takes too long. So i am looking for a solution with vectorization.

```
def std(row, data):
   data = data.loc[data['group']==row['group]]
   return data.groupby(['team']).filter(lambda x:(x['tool]!=row['team']).all())['value'].std()
df['std_exclude'] = df.apply(lambda x: std(data=df),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` after combining `group` and `team` as a list:

```
df['std'] = (df.assign(new=df[['group', 'team']].values.tolist())['new'].transform(
             lambda x: df[df['group'].eq(x[0]) & df['team'].ne(x[1])]['value'].std()))
```

Output:

```
group team value    std
0   A   1   1   2.217356
1   A   1   2   2.217356
2   A   2   5   0.816497
3   A   2   7   0.816497
4   A   3   2   2.753785
5   A   3   3   2.753785
6   B   1   7   2.217356
7   B   1   8   2.217356
8   B   2   8   1.707825
9   B   2   9   1.707825
10  B   3   6   0.816497
11  B   3   4   0.816497
```

There are some equal `std` values across different `groups` but you can verify that their `std` values are indeed equal.

Comment: Can you explain why you convert 'group' and 'team' to a list, please?

Comment: That's not the fastest way, but to be able to use `transform`, I converted `group` and `team` to one single column, that's why I needed to convert them to a list.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for, i will test it for performance. I also thought of similar solution, like transform all values and all values excluding the current row to list, then use something like  np.std((Counter(list_a) - Counter(list_b)).elements()).

Comment: Update: turns out using list inside the column is very slow. I did another method using groupby and transform the value into list then to Counter and substract them. surprisingly substracting two columns containing counter also very slow even thought it looks like a vectorized method.

Comment: Thanks for the update. groupby and transform combination are indeed a slow method for large datasets.